# How to access variable created in my less bundle?

Tags: less

I have a less bundle like that :

```
 #bundle-form {
     @inputHeight: 30px;
     .initForm(@borderColor, @borderHoverColor) { ... }
 }
```

I can easily access to my function .initForm using the following code :

```
 #bundle-form > .initForm(@grayLight, @grayDark);
```

But how to access to my @inputHeight variable ?

```
 #bundle-form > @inputHeight; // Does not work !!!
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no, you can't access namespace variables this way.
The only available method for the moment is to expand all entities of a particular namespace into current scope, e.g.:

```css
#namespace {
    @variable: 42px;

    .mixin(@a, @b) {
        // ...
    }
}

.usage {
    #namespace;       // using "#namespace" namespace here
    .mixin(1, 2);     // OK
    width: @variable; // OK
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. When you say "For the moment" do you say that some improvements maybe coming soon ?

Comment: Well, not so soon probably, [so far](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1848) there's no agreement on possible non-contradictory and issue-free syntax/implementation.